# Good html5 open source project

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to look at some examples of projects that makes heavy use of html5 canvas and does something interesting with it. The project must have source available.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend http://www.html5rocks.com/ by google

for more info read this [blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/06/html5-rocks-resource-for-open-web.html)

Answer (score 2):

You will like this site:

http://www.chromeexperiments.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)?

Comment: It uses SVG and VML, not canvas.